# I am having trouble having excel click on a best bet search result within a table from IE website

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new so sorry if this is basic. Nothing on here has helped me. I am trying to automate a function but cannot get over this issue. When I search something within the website it returns a table and clicking any of the search options is very simple as the function menu id is something simple like x1. However the chart is formatted with a "best bet" row at the top which is always the option I want it to select and this id changes depending on the variable I search so I cannot select it based on ID as it continually changes. Rather than open the function menu I just want it to click on the button in the best bet row. Any suggestions would be helpful. For context the GetElementByID("x1017538").Click is where the problem occurs.

```
Sub Mirror_Mover()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Dim MMD As Workbook
Set MMD = ThisWorkbook

Dim Mirror_Mover As Worksheet
Set Mirror_Mover = Sheets("Mirror Mover")

Dim inputRng As Range
Dim lastRow As Integer
Set inputRng = Mirror_Mover.Range("A:D")
lastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Dim Box As Range
Dim LLT As Range
Dim PRO As Range
Dim FLD As Range

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To lastRow
If inputRng(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then
Set Box = inputRng(i, 1)
Set LLT = inputRng(i, 2)
Set PRO = inputRng(i, 3)
Set FLD = inputRng(i, 4)

'Open Internet Explorer and Navigate main page
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "website"
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:05 AM#)

'Locate the item to which folder will be added
IE.Document.GetElementByID("fulltextwhere1").Value = PRO
IE.Document.GetElementByID("fulltextsubmitButton").Click
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:05 AM#)

'Open the top search result
IE.Document.GetElementByID("x1017538").Click
Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
IE.Document.GetElementByID("funcMenu101753816.1").Click
Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

```html
<TR CLASS="bestBetRow1"  TITLE="Best Bet 1">

<TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="1%" VALIGN="TOP" STYLE="padding: 3px" NOWRAP>&nbsp;<IMG HEIGHT="9" ALT="" HSPACE="3" SRC="/img/spacer.gif" WIDTH="11" BORDER="0"></TD>
<TD NOWRAP ALIGN="CENTER" TITLE="Score">

&nbsp;
</TD>

<TD NOWRAP ALIGN="CENTER" TITLE="MIME Type">







<A HREF="cs.exe?func=ll&amp;objId=1017538&amp;objAction=browse"><img class="objectIcon" src="/img/webdoc/folder.gif" alt="Folder" title="Folder"></A>
</TD>

<TD NOWRAP  TITLE="TEXT">


<SPAN CLASS="important"><A HREF="cs.exe?func=ll&amp;objId=1017538&amp;objAction=browse">TEXT</A></SPAN>
<A HREF="#" ONCLICK="setSectionName('');showFunctionMenu2('nextURL=%2Fotcs%2Fcs%2Eexe%3Ffunc%3Dsrch%2ESearchCache%26cacheId%3D697991735', '1017538', event, '', '' );setSectionName('');return false"><IMG SRC="/img/actions.png" ID="x1017538" BORDER="0" ALT="Functions" TITLE="Functions" ONMOUSEOVER="this.src='/img/actions_hover.png'" ONMOUSEOUT="this.src='/img/actions.png'"></A>
<DIV ID="z1017538" CLASS="functionMenuDiv"  ></DIV>

&nbsp;<SPAN CLASS="bestBetLabel">-&nbsp;Nickname&nbsp;(TEXT)</SPAN>

</TD>

<TD NOWRAP ALIGN="CENTER" TITLE="Date: 09/28/2017">
09/28/2017

</TD>

<TD NOWRAP ALIGN="CENTER" TITLE="Size: 21 Items">

21 Items
</TD>

<TD NOWRAP  TITLE="Location: Enterprise:TEXT">

<DIV class="search-breadcrumb-trail">
<A HREF="cs.exe?func=ll&objId=2000&objAction=browse" CLASS="locationDisplayTrailNonterminalElement" TITLE="Go to Enterprise">Enterprise</A>
<SPAN CLASS="separatorImage">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<A HREF="cs.exe?func=ll&objId=611814&objAction=browse" CLASS="locationDisplayTrailNonterminalElement" TITLE="Go to Properties">Properties</A>
<SPAN CLASS="separatorImage">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<A HREF="cs.exe?func=ll&objId=611815&objAction=browse" CLASS="locationDisplayTrailNonterminalElement" TITLE="Go to TEXT">TEXT</A>
<SPAN CLASS="separatorImage">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<A HREF="cs.exe?func=ll&objId=611882&objAction=browse" CLASS="locationDisplayTrailNonterminalElement" TITLE="Go to TEXT">TEXT</A>
<SPAN CLASS="separatorImage">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<A HREF="cs.exe?func=ll&objId=611889&objAction=browse" CLASS="locationDisplayTrailTerminalElement" TITLE="Go to TEXT">TEXT</A>
</DIV>


</TD>

<TD NOWRAP ALIGN="CENTER" TITLE="OTCreatedBy">



<A HREF="#" onClick="doUserDialog( '608559' )">Properties Folder Administrator (property_administrator)</A>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function doUserDialog( userID )
{
var  w = window.open('/cs.exe?func=user.userdialog&userID=' + userID,'UserDialog','width=600,height=440,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no');

if ( w.focus )
{
w.focus();
}
}

</SCRIPT>

</TD>

</TR>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what error you are getting. The OnClick seems to be running as you would expect, except that the function `setSectionName` is not defined (presumably this would be present in the complete page).

Comment: The only other thought is that the element `x1017538` does not have an `onClick` method, might you have to invoke the method on the parent anchor object?

Comment: Sorry I see I wasn't very clear. The x1017538 works fine but that number is unique to the first integer I am searching, when it searches the second one or any subsequent I get an error because it will be x1017545 (for example) and the code will still be trying to select x1017538. 
What I want it to do is be able to select whatever the top result is regardless of what that x# is. There is no constant id.

Comment: If it's always the top result, could you locate the A element using its position relative to another fixed element, instead of its ID - what is the containing element around the A that you want to select?

Comment: I have added more of the HTML I am pulling from, is that helpful in answering?

Answer (score 0):

Amended 2017-10-27 to take account of comments below. 
Amended 2017-11-02 to fix coding error

You could try something like the below.

Please note this code has not been compiled or debugged.

```
'// Find the best bet row <TR> element
Dim bestBetRow As Object
Set bestBetRow = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("bestBetRow1")(0)

'// Use the findRequiredLink function to find the element to be clicked
Dim link As Object
Set link = findRequiredLink(bestBetRow)

'// Check that the element is found and click it if so
If Not link Is Nothing Then
    link.Click
End If

:
:

Function findRequiredLink(parent As Object) As Object
'// This function uses recursion from a root node
'// to find a specific IMG node that meets the required
'// criteria, i.e. has the TITLE attribute set to "Functions"

    Dim child As Object
    Dim ix as integer

    '// check each child node in turn
    For ix = 0 to parent.ChildNodes.Length-1

        '// get the child node
        Set child = parent.ChildNodes.Item(ix)

        '// does it meet the required criteria?
        if child.tagName = "IMG" and _
            child.getAttribute("TITLE")="Functions" then
            set findRequiredLink = child
            exit function
        end if

        '// Recursively check the children of the child
        Set child = findRequiredLink(child)

        '// Check if the anchor was found amongst the children
        if Not child Is Nothing then
            Set findRequiredLink = child
            exit Function
        End If

    Next ix

    '// No matching node was found - return nothing
    Set findRequiredLink = Nothing
end function
```

Comment: Having a busy week and haven't been able to test this effectively yet but this looks exactly like what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: So I have it all compiled and have a few questions:

1-  Set bestBetRow = IE.Document.GetElementByID("bestBetRow1")
is there a reason you used by ID instead of class here as it doesn't look to me like this ID exists?
2- I get an error at the start of the function and it is highlighting bestbetrow1 as undefined in the line starting For ix =

Comment: Yes you are right, the statement should use `getElementsByClassName` not by ID. I guess that there is only one element with this class name, so you can assume it will be the only element returned in the collection? If not you might have to use more logic to locate the right one.

Comment: I have changed that and I am still getting an error within my function. It gives me a error 91 and points to the start of the function 
Set bestBetRow = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("bestBetRow1") as the error. I've tried changing a few different things from other error 91 questions online but still no luck.

Comment: Hmm.. Did you get the first returned element of the collection - i.e. `Set bestBetRow = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("bestBetRow1")(0)`

Comment: I also notice that getElementsByClassName() is not supported by IE8 or earlier versions. Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: I'm using post-IE8.

When I've stepped into the point where bestBetRow is set it's showing 'bestBetRow = "[objectHTMLTableRowElement]".

Comment: There was a coding error which I have fixed. In the `For ...` statement there was a reference to `bestBetRow` instead of `parent`.

Comment: Im getting an error 438 message on the same line, I'm going to keep trying to troubleshoot a few things. Thanks